# How to decrypt FormsAuthenticationTicket?

Tags: asp.net

In order to debug a production issue, I need a tool to decrypt an authentication cookie. I wrote a quick script to decrypt it using FormAuthentication.The essence is

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(source.Text);
```

The server has machineKey set and I am using the same key in this app. I am getting cookie text using Fiddler. However, I always get Unable to Validation Exception when using FormAuthentication.Decrypt. The cookie is set HttpOnly.

Am I missing something?

Note: There were a number similar questions but none of the answer has so far helped me so decided to post a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to the machine or some sort of machine related identifier. When I ran the sample script on the same server as the production server (i.e where the cookie was generated). The decryption works fine. I still haven't delve deep into finding out why so but a quick reflection of

```
System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData
```

tells that Unable_to_validate_data is thrown for pretty much any exception there.